# How to receive signal() ISR in other classes

Tags: c++, linux, signals

Right now I am developing a terminal based application that takes advantage of some display libraries.  The flow of my program is such:

```
main.cpp
\ feature1.cpp
|
\feature2.cpp
|
\ feature3.cpp
|
\feature4.cpp
```

The main class is in an infinite loop and allows you to select one of four features.  Once selected, it will enter that feature's infinite loop that will terminate once the feature reaches its exit state.  After exiting, my program returns to the main loop and allows input to be received again to select another feature.

The problem that I am having is I set a signal in the `main.cpp` file to detect when the terminal window has been resized.  If it goes below a certain size I want to do something.  Similarly, I want to do something different for each feature the user may be in.  My signal call looks like this:

```
signal(SIGWINCH, detectResize); //detectResize(int sig) handles resize
```

How could I make the signal target the correct function that corresponds to the current feature open?  Originally I tried making a method in each class called `handleResize()` and would call the `signal()` function each time to change it to the correct class.  For example:

```
if(feature1 is selected)
{
    signal(SIGWINCH, f1.handleResize);
    feature1 f1(); //start feature 1 loop
}
```

This didn't work because I couldn't figure out how to pass `f1.handleResize` in before I create the object.  I'm not too experienced with C++.  Is there a better way to go about this?  If it were Java, I was thinking of making a `Resize` interface (class for C++) and making each feature implement it.  Then I could keep track of which feature is being used via some global variable and call the appropriate `<feature>.handleResize()` from the `handleResize()` function in `main.cpp`.  Would something like this be a possibility or are there more elegant methods for C++?

Comment: This is a Unix/Linux question, not a c++ question. Please re-tag.

Comment: @JiveDadson OK, I added the Linux tag.